# The PDF file starts with the header %pdf. Can a valid pdf file have more than 1 such headers?

Tags: pdf

The PDF file starts with the header %pdf. Can a valid pdf file have more than 1 such headers?
The Pdf specification says that it can have more than 1 trailers. But it does not talk about multiple headers. Can it have multiple headers?

Comment: To be more precise, the header starts with `%PDF`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can have as many as you want, since the symbol `%` is used to represent comments inside a PDF file, so it's not actually a "header".

From the PDF specification:

> 7.2.3 Comments
>
> Any occurrence of the PERCENT SIGN (25h) outside a string or stream
>   introduces a comment. The comment consists of all characters after the
>   PERCENT SIGN and up to but not including the end of the line,
>   including regular, delimiter, SPACE (20h), and HORZONTAL TAB
>   characters (09h). A conforming reader shall ignore comments, and treat
>   them as single white-space characters. That is, a comment separates
>   the token preceding it from the one following it.
>
> EXAMPLE:
>
> The PDF fragment in this example is syntactically equivalent to just
>   the tokens abc and 123. abc% comment ( /%) blah blah blah 123